# How to send multiple attachment in laravel mail

Tags: php, laravel

I created an two separate excel files `$recent_signup_file, $ddr_failed_file`, and attach on laravel mailer

```
Mail::send('emails.weeklyreports', ['data' => $data], function($message) use ($recipient, $subject_date, $recent_signup_file, $ddr_failed_file) {
   $message->from('support@whitebelt.co', 'Whitebelt.co Support');
   $message->to($recipient)->subject('Weekly Report '.$subject_date);
   $message->addAttachment($recent_signup_file->store("xlsx",false,true)['full']);
   $message->addAttachment($ddr_failed_file->store("xlsx",false,true)['full']);
});
```

But it gives me duplicate excel file, its this is right or did i miss something, can anyone help me.

How do I it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Laravel are you using? You should be using a Mailable if you are using Laravel 5.4+, something that looks like this:

```
Mail::to($recipient)->send(new WeeklyReport($data));
```

Within the WeeklyReport mailable, you would attach your files and pass an array of your data to the view like this:

```
class WeeklyReport extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
         $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.weeklyreports', $this->data)
                ->from('support@whitebelt.co', 'Whitebelt.co Support')
                ->attach($this->data['recent_signup_file']->store("xlsx",false,true)['full'])
                ->attach($this->data['ddr_failed_file']->store("xlsx",false,true)['full']);
    }
}
```

See the Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail).

This all assumes that your functions that you're using to create the excel sheets are actually working as intended. Since we don't see that code here, I can't comment on its functionality. But the above is the correct way to attach files with Laravel 5.4+.

Comment: I used Task Scheduling - Laravel that send mail with attachment every week, I used also laravel 5.5

Comment: Try using a Mailable as shown above in my answer. Your code does not follow the Laravel documentation for the Mail facade for Laravel 5.5. I have sent many emails with multiple attachments using the method shown above and have had no problems. Again, this assumes that your code for generating the files is not faulty, which I can't guarantee without seeing it.